# linq to sql Cannot implicitly convert type... error

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I always catch error in getting strongly typed value from my query. 
I need to get DateTime variable from such query

```
        var lastdateindex = (from c in v.db.TotalDoc
                             select c).Max(id => id.TotalID);
        var lastdate = (from c in v.db.TotalDoc
                        where c.TotalID == lastdateindex
                        select c.TotalDate);
        List<DateTime> list = lastdate.ToList();
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

i don't know what should i do. please help. thank you

Comment: Please post the *exact* error you're getting.

Comment: catch error in List<DateTime> list =  lastdate.ToList()

Comment: I'm sure the exact error wasn't just "catch error". Cut and past the error message you've got. Also tell us the type of `TotalDate`. Is it `DateTime?` (i.e. nullable) by any chance?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime?>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>'

Comment: Right, as I suspected... will add answer now.

Comment: @bragin.www now you understand why is crucial to read the error

Comment: TotalDate is a field (datetime) in sql compact database

Comment: @AdrianIftode - And as crucial, to _post_ the error details.

Comment: yes, ok i have forgotten in case of my worry

Comment: @Oded, indeed, and maybe if the OP would have read the error, he wouldn't ask here for a solution.

Comment: @bragin.www, you can accept Jon's answer (tick the accept mark)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `TotalDate` type is `DateTime?`, not `DateTime`. Now if you're *sure* that all rows will have a value, you could use:

```
var lastDateIndex = v.db.TotalDoc.Max(id => id.TotalID);
var lastDate = from c in v.db.TotalDoc
               where c.TotalID == lastDateIndex
               select c.TotalDate.Value;
List<DateTime> list = lastDate.ToList();
```

Or you might want to *only* pick those rows with a date:

```
var lastDateIndex = v.db.TotalDoc.Max(id => id.TotalID);
var lastDate = from c in v.db.TotalDoc
               where c.TotalID == lastDateIndex && c.TotalDate != null
               select c.TotalDate.Value;
List<DateTime> list = lastDate.ToList();
```

Comment: it works. thank you very much. hope in future i will understand this language. its realy beautifull